# Scrape website that uses javascript with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape a website using the following code

```
import re
import requests

def get_csrf(page):
    matchme = r'name="csrfToken" value="(.*)" /'
    csrf = re.search(matchme, str(page))
    csrf = csrf.group(1)
    return csrf

def login():
    login_url = 'https://www.edline.net/InterstitialLogin.page'

    with requests.Session() as s:
        login_page = s.get(login_url)
        csrf = get_csrf(login_page.text)

        username = 'USER'
        password = 'PASS'

        login = {'screenName': username,
                 'kclq': password,
                 'csrfToken': csrf,
                 'TCNK':'authenticationEntryComponent',
                 'submitEvent':'1',
                 'enterClicked':'true',
                 'ajaxSupported':'yes'}
        page = s.post(login_url, data=login)
        r = s.get("https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page?")
        print(r.text)

login()
```

Where I log into https://www.edline.net/InterstitialLogin.page, which is successful, but the problem I have is when I try to do

```
r = s.get("https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page?")
print(r.text)
```

It doesn't print the expected page, instead it throws an error. Upon further testing I discovered that it throws this error even if you try to go directly to the page from a browser. So when I investigated the page source I found that the button used to link to the page I'm trying to scrape uses the following code

```
<a href="javascript:submitEvent('viewUserDocList', 'TCNK=headerComponent')" tabindex="-1">Private Reports</a>
```

So essentially I am looking for a way to trigger the above javascript code in python in order to scrape the resulting page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping with python and executing javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294205/scraping-with-python-and-executing-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to answer this question without having more context than this single link.

However, the first thing you want to check, in the case of javaScript driven content generation, are the requests made by your web page when clicking on that link.

To do this, take a look at the network-panel in the console of your browser. Record the requests being made, look especially for XHR-requests. Then, you can try to replicate this e.g. with the requests library.

content = requests.get('xhr-url')

Comment: I did that, and I'm not sure if I did it right but I don't see any xhr requests...